# Somar valores de uma coluna na tabela onde a data se repete, em um SUB-SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

As datas estão diferentes em suas horas como esse exemplo:

```
+---------------------+-------------------+-------+
| DATA                | callid            | tempo |
+---------------------+-------------------+-------+
| 2021-08-01 12:23:50 | 1627831011.78021  |   345 |
| 2021-08-01 17:08:26 | 1627848459.79020  |    12 |
| 2021-08-03 08:58:24 | 1627905500.80140  |     2 |
| 2021-08-04 09:28:01 | 1627907135.80426  |   114 |
```

Queria somar e fazer a media com esses 2 primeiros registros da `2021-08-01`, ou seja  só com os dias que se repetem.

Tentei Usar o `AVG()`(para fazer a media dos valores domados) e `SUM()` mas não funciona da seguinte erro: `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

```
SELECT c.DATA,
       c.callid,
       AVG(SUM(c.tempo)) AS tempo_medio
FROM   (SELECT q.calldate     AS DATA,
               callid,
               ROUND(q.info2) AS tempo
        FROM   queuelog AS q
               LEFT JOIN asteriskcdrdb.cdr o
                      ON o.uniqueid = q.callid
               LEFT JOIN cdrjuncao cj
                      ON o.uniqueid = cj.uniqueid
                         AND o.calldate = cj.calldate
        WHERE  timestamp BETWEEN '1627786800' AND '1630551599'
               AND ( agent = '9043'
                      OR agent = '9043' )
               AND ( qname = '717'
                      OR qname = '721'
                      OR qname = '701' )
               AND action IN ( 'COMPLETEAGENT', 'COMPLETECALLER', 'TRANSFER' )
               AND o.uniqueid NOT IN ( '' )) c
GROUP  BY c.DATA;
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar? vlwss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nem entrarei no mérito de tentar entender o que são as tabelas `queuelog`, `asteriskcdrdb.cdr` e `cdrjuncao`, pois não ficou claro qual é a relação delas com o problema.

Você fez `GROUP  BY c.DATA`, mas como a coluna possui o horário, estará agrupando a cada segundo e não pela data. O código não reflete a sua intenção.

E fez também `AVG(SUM(c.tempo))`. Isso fez sentido para você? A função `AVG` já faz a soma e divide pela quantidade, que é a definição da média aritmética, então não precisa somar antes. A média de 2 e 4 é 3, mas qual seria a média de 6, que é a soma dos dois?

Por fim, o código ficaria simplesmente parecido com:

```sql
SELECT DATE(`DATA`), AVG(`tempo`)
FROM tempos
GROUP BY DATE(`DATA`)
```

Produz um resultado parecido com:

| DATE(`DATA`) | AVG(`tempo`) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 | 178.5000 |
| 2021-08-03 | 2.0000 |
| 2021-08-04 | 114.0000 |

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Woss ! eu entendi que não precisa somar com o metodo `AVG()` e tinha esquecido do `DATE()`, com o sua resposta e exemplo consegui oque eu queria :)   OBS:As tabelas `queuelog`, `asteriskcdrdb.cdr` e  `cdrjuncao` não tem relação com o problema falha minha.